# Simple Objective C program to Create tabbarcontroller to display a viewcontroller without selecting any TabBaritems

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Objective C. I created a TabBarController with 5 ViewController. I'm looking for an Objective C code to Display a ViewController without selecting any TabBarItem and also TabBar as to display 4 Items for selecting other ViewController. I'm using Xcode 6.6.1 and Mac 10.10.2 Kindly assist.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. You about to ask that a view controller should be selected by default at the begging?

Comment: what did you try to implement this? paste some code

Comment: Hai Lalit,  Actually I'm trying to Design TabBarController with 5 child viewcontroller But i need one ViewController act as SplashViewController.

Comment: Hai Mithun, Yes I need a view controller should be selected by default But it's BarButton item has to be hidden.TabBar have BarButtonItem for other ViewController

Comment: What will appear where the bar button item would have been if it was not invisible?

Comment: [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]setHidden:YES];

Comment: [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]setHidden:YES]; while Running above code I'm getting Error like this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tabbaritem.' and i need to Display ViewController when i Do like [self.tabBar.Items SetSelected:Nil]

Comment: Hello Manasa: So you mean to say that, if you have 5 view controller as the items for tab and you need to display sixth item initially, which should not be in the tab bar item itself and also when you loading this sixth VC initially, you don't wanna display or select any items from the tab bar. Im i right?

Comment: Hai Mithun, Absolutely right.